# Populate Value of a Cell Below a specific cell based on matching cells in different Column

Tags: excel

Can I get the Excel code for if 2 rows have equal Timestamp, Last Name and First Name, copy the Company Name from the first row to the second row?

In the example below, only the first and second rows match, so the Company Name in the second row should be populated with Company A

[image: Example]

Comment: @Vityata And why remove a table, which can be easily copy/pasted into a worksheet, with a screenshot, which is more difficult to use?

Comment: @Vityata My comment was not meant to implicate you as the perpetrator, only as an extension of your criticism.  I tagged it with your name so you would be sure to see it.  There was a table initially, and then that was removed and a screenshot substituted.  Didn't know where in that sequence your comment was posted.

Comment: Add a Search column with Timestamp, Last Name and First Name concatenated, use then vlookup and try to get company name.

Comment: There are examples of similar questions on SO.  What have you tried and where have you run into problems?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I see, ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about you try the following to see if it works out for you:

```
=IF(A2&B2&C2=A3&B3&C3;D2;"")
```